# Python bcrypt TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before checking

Tags: python, bcrypt

I am trying to make a secure login system using `bcrypt` (Python).

Now the error that I am getting is `TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before checking`.
I know that `bcrypt`'s `checkpw()` only takes `bytes` as a datatype, but as you can see in the code it should already be encoded to that datatype.

Here are the error messages:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\olive\OneDrive\Dokumenter\Files\skole docs\Programering\test\Fixornot.py", line 37, in 
> logreg()
>
> File "C:\Users\olive\OneDrive\Dokumenter\Files\skole docs\Programering\test\Fixornot.py", line 29, in logreg
> login(logname, logpass)
>
> File "C:\Users\olive\OneDrive\Dokumenter\Files\skole docs\Programering\test\Fixornot.py", line 20, in login
> bcrypt.checkpw(logpass, hashed)
>
> File "C:\Users\olive\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\bcrypt_*init*_.py",
> line 120, in checkpw
> raise TypeError("Unicode-objects must be encoded before checking")
>
> TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before checking

Here is the code ([github](https://github.com/It-Snorlaxy/HashLogSystem/blob/main/test/Fixornot.py)):

```
import bcrypt
import hashlib
LR = None

salt = bcrypt.gensalt()

def register ():
    print('Making a user')
    user = input('Navn: ')
    hashed = bcrypt.hashpw(input('password: ').encode('utf-8'), salt)
    file = open('user_details.txt','a')
    file.write(user + ',' + str(hashed) + ',' + str(salt) + '\n')
    file.close()
    logreg()

def login (logname, logpass):
    file = open('user_details.txt','r')
    for i in file:
        user, hashed, salt = i.split(',')
    bcrypt.checkpw(logpass, hashed)
    file.close()

def logreg():
    loginregist = input('log/reg? ')
    if loginregist == 'log':
        print('Du er ved at logge ind')
        logname = input('Navn: ')
        logpass = bcrypt.hashpw(input('password: ').encode('utf-8'), salt)
        login(logname, logpass)
    elif loginregist == 'reg':
        register()
    else:
        logreg()



logreg()
```

Comment: It looks like when you are reading in that file in line 18, it is not reading in bytes objects. Try converting them to bytes before calling `checkpw` in line 20.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix your error: in line 17 of that Github page, change the mode from `'r'` to `'rb'`. If you use the former (as an example)

```
with open("blankpaper.txt", 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        print(type(line))
```

you will see that the type of `line` is `<class 'str'>`. If you replace `'r'` with `'rb'` in this code, you will see that the type of `line` is `<class 'bytes'>`, which is what you want.

In line 19, change `','` to `b','` as `i` is meant to be a `bytes` object.

After making these changes you no longer should be getting

```
TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before checking
```

However, there are other places in your code that could be generating errors.

We know that we need to be working with `bytes` objects but there are several places where unicode strings are used where `bytes` strings should be used instead.

Change

```
user = input('Navn: ')
```

to

```
user = input('Navn: ').encode()
```

Change these two lines

```
file = open('user_details.txt','a')
file.write(user + ',' + str(hashed) + ',' + str(salt) + '\n')
```

to

```
file = open('user_details.txt','ab')
file.write(user + b',' + hashed + b',' + salt + b'\n')
```

After making these changes, I was able to successfully run a session whereby I registered my username and password followed by logging in. There were no errors.

Please let me know if there are any questions. I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much. It helped after some trail and error, we got it working thanks to your advice. You just saved our exam.

Comment: @Anonymous Happy I could help! If my answer fixes your issue, please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark next to my answer. This is completely optional and no love would be lost if you do not!